# how to fix type mismatch error?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Hi I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim str() As String

Name = surname.Value

With ws
Set f = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not f Is Nothing Then
With Me
    firstname.Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
    tod.Value = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
    program.Value = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
    email.Value = f.Offset(0, 4).Text

    SetCheckBoxes f.Offset(0, 5) '<<< replaces code below

    officenumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 6).Text
    cellnumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 7).Text
    r = f.Row '<<<<<<<<< using this to locate the row of "found"
End With
    findnext
        FirstAddress = f.Address
Do
    s = s + 1
    Set f = Range("A:A").findnext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> FirstAddress
    If s > 1 Then
       Select Case MsgBox("There are " & s & " instances of " & Name, vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Multiple entries")

       Case vbOK
            findnext
       Case vbCancel

       End Select

    End If

Else: MsgBox Name & "Not Listed"

End If

End With

End Sub
```

and i want to use an update button:

```
private Sub update_Click()

Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

With ws
Set f = .Cells(r, 1)  '<<<<<<<<<<<<< Mismatch type error

    f.Value = surname.Value
    f.Offset(0, 1).Value = firstname.Value
    f.Offset(0, 2).Value = tod.Value
    f.Offset(0, 3).Value = program.Value
    f.Offset(0, 4).Value = email.Value
    f.Offset(0, 5).Value = GetCheckBoxes
    f.Offset(0, 6).Value = officenumber.Value
    f.Offset(0, 7).Value = cellnumber.Value

End With
End Sub
```

so i want to locate the row of the found cell and replace all the cells to whatever is written in the textbox (updating the previous infomration with new information) - however i get an error on set f = .cells(r,1) how can i fix this?

Comment: `r` isn't declared in your 2nd Sub. You need to declare it globally if you want to set it in one sub and use it in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use global variable `r`: instead declaring `Dim r As Long` in `Private Sub Search_Click()`, use `Public r As Long` *outside* all functions in the very top of module :

```
Public r As Long

Public Sub Search_Click()
'your code
End Sub

Public Sub update_Click()
'your code
End Sub
```

Now, after calling `Search_Click` `r` would be inizialized and then you could call `update_Click`.

P.S. Don't forget to remove `Dim r As Long` from `Private Sub Search_Click()`.

BTW, in your `update_Click` and `Search_Click` subs you haven't initialized `ws` variable: `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. After adding this line change `Range("A:A")` to `.Range("A:A")` in `Search_Click`

Comment: I've inserted public r at the very top, removed dim r from search_click and i've changed the subs to public but now it's givign me a .cells(r,1) = <Object variable or with block variable not set>

Comment: it's because in your `update_Click` and `Search_Click` subs you haven't initialized `ws` variable: use something like this: `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: btw, after adding `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`, change `Range("A:A")` to `.Range("A:A")` in `Search_Click`